# How to get a machine name of a custom block

Tags: 8, blocks

I have a custom "Slider Items" field type, as well as the custom "Channel Slider Block Type" type block (created using "Custom block library").

[image: ...]

[image: ...]

Also, I have several "Channel Slider Block Type" blocks.  I need to somehow determine the machine name of a block that this field displays in @FieldFormatter of my field. How can this be implemented? Perhaps there is a special service for this?

```
/**
 * @FieldFormatter(
 *   id = "channel_slider_formatter",
 *   label = @Translation("Channel Slider Formatter"),
 *   field_types = {
 *     "channel_slider"
 *   }
 * )
 */
class ChannelSliderFormatter extends FormatterBase {

  public function viewElements(FieldItemListInterface $items, $langcode) {
    // Here I need to get a block that reflects this field.
    $blockMachineName = '...';
    ...
    return [
      '#theme' => 'channel_slider',
      '#items' => $itemsData,
    ];
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom blocks do not have machine name since they are content entities. What you can do is to check the bundle of the block in your field formatter.

```
public function viewElements(FieldItemListInterface $items, $langcode) {
  if ($items->isEmpty()) {
    return NULL;
  }

  $entity = $items->first()->getEntity();
  if ($entity->getTargetEntityTypeId() === 'block_custom') {
     // Heres my great block type.
     $block_type = $entity->bundle();
     // Do something with it.
  }

  // The usual sutff.
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! Bundle is what I need.. Incredibly grateful to you.

Answer (score 2):

A custom content block has no unique machine name, only a bundle type, an UUID and an ID. Only custom content blocks placed in a region have a machine name, but this is NOT the machine name of the block, it is the machine name of the block placement (configuration)

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! This brought clarity.